# Way to clear cache from settings in app?

Tags: xamarin.ios

Trying to find a way to clear the cache the app uses over time that's found in the settings page on the iPhone.

Essentially, we implemented a pinch/pan page on our app using Xamarin Forms. We've been serving this page huge images, because we want the images to be clear when you zoom in on them. We're seeing a huge uptick in people complaining that the app is storing too much. We want a way to clear this cache every week or so, to prevent this.

Is there a way to clear the phones cache for that app in the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer:

```cs
var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
var cache = System.IO.Path.Combine(documents, ".config", ".isolated-storage", "ImageLoaderCache");

foreach (var file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(cache))
{
    System.IO.File.Delete(file);
}
```